# How to use list item value in multiple datatables C#?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datatable

am trying to build a Windows trading application using C# WinForms. I have successfully connected the price feed to my application through a WebSocket and stored the last price of each symbol in a Datatable(prices).

I also have another Datatable(orders) that stores all the open orders, so in order to calculate the current profit/loss I had to link the prices and the orders datatables using a dataset so I can have the last price to perform my calculations.

But I noticed that updating the prices datatable is so slow especially upon major economical events resulting in delaying price processing, so I replaced the prices datatable with a list.

Now the price processing is much faster with tiny delays that can be neglected. But my problem is how can I link my prices list to my orders datatable so whenever any price changes in my list it will be automatically reflected in my orders datatable? is there a way that i can set pointer for each order row to a specific list item price?

thank you

Comment: Why was your first solution slow?  Too many updates?  Are you writing back to the database?  I'd tackle that issue really because you're basically trying to implement it yourself now.  One way I workaround rapid price updates in trading apps is to apply them every so often using a timer.  Like 200 milliseconds.

Comment: what do you mean by applying them every so often? I have a price feed and i need to update the price with every new price tick. I have a listener running so whenever a new price update arrives i should update the price for that symbol. it is actually working fine but the delays happens upon major events and at the US market opening.

Comment: "the delays happens upon major events and at the US market opening." - you answered your own question.  You have a performance problem.  Why a timer?  Because it solves for market volatility and won't change performance if update frequency increases.  Whereas your solution, apply immediately, has an upper limit no matter how well implemented because market data can update incredibly fast.  Did you try a profiler to optimize?  My solution works too, it just might delay the price update by a maximum of 200 ms.  Store prices by symbol somewhere, then actually apply all changed prices on interval.

Comment: no not actually can you share with me how to use a profiler. i actually never used it before. and by applying changes every 200 ms, u mean to store all events in a queue and apply it upon timer event? thank you my friend.

Comment: How to use a profiler is off topic here, but Visual Studio has built-in profilers and you can look around for how to use that.  There are also third party ones, mostly commercial (not free).  As for an implementation, sure I'll post one.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve performance for price updates that may become rapid is to batch them.  Effectively you store only the most recent price update per instrument, then you apply the update on a fairly quick timer.  How often is up to you.

Simple example below, but there are many different ways you can batch apply price updates.

```
public class PriceUpdater
{
    //The key can be anything unqiue, but here I'll just assume symbol works
    private readonly Dictionary<string, double> pricesBySymbol = 
        new Dictionary<string, double>();

    private readonly Timer timer;

    public PriceUpdater()
    {
        timer = new Timer(ApplyPrices);
        //This starts the timer now, and interval of 200 millis
        timer.Change(0, 200);
    }

    //Lets presume this is called for every last price tick
    //If this gets called by multiple threads add synchronization
    public void HandleLastPriceTick(string symbol, double price)
    {
        pricesBySymbol[symbol] = price;
    }

    public void ApplyPrices(object state)
    {
        //iterate over the dictionary and apply the prices everywhere else
        //that's performance critical
        foreach(var item in pricesBySymbol)
        {
            string symbol = item.Key;
            double price = item.Value;
            //Raise an event, or call a method here to apply the change
        }
        //Alternatively, do a bulk update however you want using the latest prices
    }
}
```

Doing something like this still applies all price updates, it just does so in batches X often.  And makes performance stable even in times of high frequency market updates.

**Pros**

Can handle incredibly high update speeds without impacting performance

Relatively easy to make thread-safe

Can combine this with another design where requirements demand they receive all updates immediately

**Cons**

This only grabs the most recent price and is not suitable if you need all ticks processed

The above implementation does not store if a price has changed, or a new tick came in per instrument.  You may want to implement that to skip applying stale values.